# sigcancel received on std::thread, aborted

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I have a thread created using std::thread. This thread is waiting for the work to arrive on the shared list. The main thread will post the message on this list and notify this thread via condition variable. When this thread was in waiting state it randomly received cancel signal and the thread aborted. Copying the coredump trace as well. Can someone please help me on what are the possible reason for such observation? Is it possible that the kernel of the K8s worker node sending this cancel signal?

Note: The below thread is running inside container environment (i.e. in K8s cluster)

```
void Task::waitForWork()
{
    // Wait until there is something in the list
    // requestList_.count() function uses a mutex
    while( (!quit_) && (requestList_.count() == 0) )     
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(reqListMutex_);
        // Block until there is any message in the list
        condVar_.wait(lock);
        if(quit_)
        {
            return;
        }
        RequestMsg* req = requestList_.getRequest();
        if (req != 0)
        {
           // Proceed with the req msg
        }
    }
}


void Task::Start(){
   // thread_ is a member of Task Class
   thread_ = std::thread(&Task::waitForWork, this);
}
void Task::Stop(){
    // Notify task to quit
    quit_ = true;
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(reqListMutex_);
        condVar_.notify_one();
    }
    if(thread_.joinable()){
        thread_.join();
    }
}
```

Coredump back trace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7510535 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x0000555555e46f47 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() [clone .cold.1] () at /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:86
#3  0x00005555565ddb76 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)()) ()
#4  0x00005555565ddbb1 in std::terminate() ()
#5  0x00005555565de2f4 in __gxx_personality_v0 ()
#6  0x00007ffff549cf28 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007ffff549d51c in _Unwind_ForcedUnwind () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007ffff7df90a0 in __GI___pthread_unwind (buf=<optimized out>) at unwind.c:121
#9  0x00007ffff7dee73a in __do_cancel () at ./pthreadP.h:305
#10 sigcancel_handler (sig=32, si=0x7fffd37fd3f0, ctx=<optimized out>) at nptl-init.c:200
#11 sigcancel_handler (sig=<optimized out>, si=0x7fffd37fd3f0, ctx=<optimized out>) at nptl-init.c:165
#12 <signal handler called>
#13 futex_wait_cancelable (private=0, expected=0, futex_word=0x555556ab0c48 <condVar_+40>) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/futex-internal.h:88
#14 __pthread_cond_wait_common (abstime=0x0, mutex=0x555556ada7a0, cond=0x555556ab0c20 <condVar_>) at pthread_cond_wait.c:502
#15 __pthread_cond_wait (cond=0x555556ab0c20 <condVar_>, mutex=0x555556ada7a0) at pthread_cond_wait.c:655
#16 0x000055555666129c in std::condition_variable::wait(std::unique_lock<std::mutex>&) ()
```

Comment: What is it that the mutex is supposed to protect? If it's the list, then you're clearly accessing it from outside a lock. Use the condition variable to wait for something, using a short lambda function, as an elegant alterative to writing all that code yourself. That said, it's unclear what sends the signal, so for a better picture, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I missed your point. I'm not accessing it outside the lock. The count function acquires lock. Unfortunately I could not reproduce this and happened only once! It was a random cancel signal. The application never calls it explicitly.

Comment: @RajaNarayan It looks like `quit_` is the condition associated with `condVar_` and `reqListMutex_` the associated mutex. Even if `quit_` is atomic you still need the associated mutex to be locked to avoid the chance of missing a notification. Changing the condition and notifying the `conditional_variable` effectively has to be atomic or you have to be tolerant to missed notifications (which is hard without making the use of `condition_variable` redundant).

Comment: yes quit_ is atomic. If there is no request, it waits on the condition variable for any notification to arrive.

Comment: @RajaNarayan `wait` can sporadically wake up without a notification having been sent. In that case `getRequest` needs to handle an empty request list. As mentioned in the comment above, you also may be missing notifications, especially the notification to quit.

Comment: `SIGCANCEL` is an internal implementation detail from `pthread_cancel`, not a standard signal. It's probably generated internally by the `std::thread` implementation.

Comment: Once you check if it's empty, you unlock the mutex, leaving it up for grabs by other threads. Whether it's still empty then is impossible to say. You have a race condition there. I'm now voting to close, for one there are obvious errors like this one, further there is no [mcve] here and extracting that is required. Also, it helps you figure things out yourself.

Comment: Your current code drops the lock before reacquiring it for the condition variable. You could end up missing a notification because you don't check the conditions again after reacquiring the lock. You should use something like `condVar_.wait(lock, [this]() { return quit_ || !requestList_.empty(); });`. instead, which will also help with spurious wakeups